# Account' object has no attribute 'sign_decorated

Tags: horizon, python-sdk

I am trying to pay 2 tokens and I am getting this error:

```
sig = signer.sign_decorated(tx_hash)
AttributeError: 'Account' object has no attribute 'sign_decorated'
```

My code given below:

```
def transfer_amount(receiver_address, receiver_secret, customer_transaction_id):
    print('Transferring Amount to {}'.format(receiver_address))
    server = Server(horizon_url="https://horizon.stellar.org")

    # This is distributer account
    funding_keypair = Keypair.from_secret(settings.FUNDING_SECRET)
    funding_public_key = funding_keypair.public_key
    funding_account = server.load_account(funding_public_key)

    ISSUER = 'GBZO6TJRF3GHXV4QM34UEBASA5MMFODM6EYDHOYTN4DNDGM3Y2XXKCYT'  # For DEV COIN

    receiving_account = Keypair.from_secret(receiver_secret)

    transaction = (
        TransactionBuilder(
            source_account=funding_account,
            network_passphrase=Network.PUBLIC_NETWORK_PASSPHRASE,
            base_fee=server.fetch_base_fee(),
        )
            .add_text_memo('Ref: {}'.format(customer_transaction_id))
            .append_payment_op(receiver_address, '2', 'DEV', ISSUER)
            .build()
    )
    transaction.sign(funding_account)
    response = server.submit_transaction(transaction)
    print(response)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should sign the transaction with `Keypair`.

```python
transaction.sign(funding_keypair)
```